# Why am I getting "Expected getter method not found"?

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4.5

I was working on an iphone database app and I got "expected getter method not found".I don't get why I'm getting the message. I tried all sorts of troubleshooting. It's in this line of code:

```
NSString *inserStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PERSONS(NAME,AGE)  values   ('%s' '%d')",[self.Namefield.text UTF8String],[self.ageField.text intValue]];
```

Here's the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfPerson;
    sqlite3 *personDB;
    NSString *dbPathString;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrayOfPerson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [[self myTableView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self myTableView]setDataSource:self];
    [self createOrOpenDB]; 
}

-(void)createOrOpenDB
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"persons.db"];

    char *error;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]) {
        const char *dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY   KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, AGE INTEGER)";
            sqlite3_exec(personDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_close(personDB);
        }
    }
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfPerson count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc ]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    Person *aPerson = [arrayOfPerson objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = aPerson.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aPerson.age];

    return cell;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)AddPersonButton:(id)sender {

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *inserStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PERSONS(NAME,AGE)  values ('%s' '%d')",[self.Namefield.text UTF8String],[self.ageField.text intValue]];
    }
}

- (IBAction)DisplayPersonButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)deletePersonButton:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Can somebody please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this error is telling that , you have to need getter method, i.e. we have to write getter for our properties, if we synthesize them, then ios internally implements the getter method for us. thats why you have to synthesize your properties .

```
@implementation ViewController
@Synthesize NameField,ageField;//property synthesized
// remaining code
@end
```